# counter table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

i was going through the book: [High performance MySql 2nd edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449314287). In chapter 4 it says:

> An application that keeps counts in a table can run into concurrency
>   problems when updating the counters. Such tables are very common in
>   web applications.
>
> To keep things as simple as possible, suppose you have a counter table
>   with a single row that just counts hits on your website:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE hit_counter ( cnt int unsigned not null ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```
>
> Each hit on the website updates the counter:
>
> ```
> mysql> UPDATE hit_counter SET cnt = cnt + 1;
> ```
>
> The problem is that this single row is effectively a global “mutex”
>   for any transaction that updates the counter. It will serialize those
>   transactions. You can get higher concurrency by keeping more than one
>   row and updating a random row.
>
> Below is the change:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE (slot tinyint unsigned not null primary key, cnt int unsigned not null ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```
>
> Prepopulate the table by adding 100 rows to it. Now the query can just
>   choose a random slot and update it:
>
> `mysql> UPDATE hit_counter SET cnt = cnt + 1 WHERE slot = RAND() *
>   100;`
>
> To retrieve statistics, just use aggregate queries:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM hit_counter;
> ```

**Here comes my doubt:**

As there are two different queries one which increment the `cnt` and other which calculate the sum of `cnt` than how come it will give correct result to two different threads executing simultaneously? For example `t1` fires the first query to increase the `cnt`  , before it fetches the sum t2 also updates the `cnt` than the 2nd query for t1  will fetch wrong result. Please clarify.

if you dont have the book please refer [this](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=D0b_Xg3UeXEC&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=To%20keep%20things%20as%20simple%20as%20possible,%20suppose%20you%20have%20a%20counter%20table%20with%20a%20single%20row%20that%20just%20counts%20hits%20on%20your%20website%3a&source=bl&ots=RZTf_XKy-x&sig=WXBN6fP9xXXU-3HlshRSDZasS4M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=l9RgUvulDcfHrQe-tYH4Cw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=To%20keep%20things%20as%20simple%20as%20possible,%20suppose%20you%20have%20a%20counter%20table%20with%20a%20single%20row%20that%20just%20counts%20hits%20on%20your%20website%3a&f=false).

Answer (score 2):

It's the ***transaction isolation*** that guarantees consistent results.

In your example, if you are concerned about possible changes from other threads between the first and the second query, you should enclose your queries in a single transaction: this is implicit if you have `autocommit` disabled, otherwise can be explicitly declared:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE hit_counter SET cnt = cnt + 1 WHERE slot = RAND() * 100;
SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM hit_counter;
COMMIT;
```

But it must also be said that, in many real use cases (like a counter for visits on a web page), having a result which is consistent with the previous increment is not so important.

For a deep explanation about possible transaction isolation levels please refer to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html